# Are solutions of $\frac{1}{2}(A^T+A)x=b$ and $Ax=b$ related?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw some statements about these 2 systems while I was reading something about linear algebra. So I am curious if the solutions of these 2 systems are related. If it is, how are they related?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: The equations are identical when $A$ is a symmetric matrix, that is $A=A^T$, otherwise the equation on the right features a contribution from the antisymmetric part of $A$ which is not present in the equation on the left and thus it's solution should be independent. Any matrix can be written as the sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric part, $A=S+R$, $S=S^T,R=-R^T$.

Comment: The systems $$x^T \frac{1}{2} (A^T + A) x = t  $$ and $$ x^T A x = t$$ are related for $t$ a scalar.

Comment: There is always some relation; the question is whether this relation is somehow interesting, simple, useful... e.g., if $A=H+S$, where $H=(A^T+A)/2$, then $y=H^{-1}b$ and $x=A^{-1}b$ are related by $y-x=A^{-1}SH^{-1}b$.

Comment: @WillJagy Note that solutions of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x=b$ and $Ax=b$ are different, so there are two different $x$'s here.

Comment: Consider the case where $A$ is antisymmetric. The first equation says $0x=b$. What relation is there between the solutions, if any, to this equation, and to $Ax=b$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess the author would like to assume that both $A$ and $A+A^T$ are nonsingular, or at least the systems are solvable (when talking about *solutions*). If $A$ is anti-symmetric, the first system is solvable only if $b=0$ and in such a case, $0$ is a solution of both systems [there would be a very nice relation between them then:)]

Answer (score 3):

We define the equations and vectors $\boldsymbol{x}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_{2}$:

$$A\boldsymbol{x}_{1}=\boldsymbol{b}$$

$$\cfrac{1}{2}(A+A^{T})\boldsymbol{x_{2}}=\boldsymbol{b}$$

Then, suppose to describe $\boldsymbol{x_{2}}$ using $A$ , $\boldsymbol{b}$ and $\boldsymbol{x_{1}}$. According to the formula as [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), an inverse matrix can be transformed as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{x_{2}}
&=2(A+A^{T})^{-1}\boldsymbol{b} \\
&=2\{A^{-1}-A^{-1}A^{T}(I+A^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}A^{-1}\}\boldsymbol{b} \\
&=2\{I- \ U(I+U)^{-1}\}\boldsymbol{x_{1}}
\end{align}
$$

where, $U=A^{-1}A^{T}$ and $I$ is an identity matrix. Particularly, if $A$ is a symmentric matrix, $U=I$ is established. Therefore:

$$\boldsymbol{x_{2}}=\boldsymbol{x}_{1}$$

In conclusion, there is a relation between $\boldsymbol{x_{1}}$ and $\boldsymbol{x_{2}}$.